# Html Content To Pdf Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html-to-pdf

I want to convert HTML content to pdf. It can be any content i.e. content of a div, table etc.

I have tried jspdf, iText for it but they are not effective.

Among the paid one's pdfcrowd is solving my purpose but I am looking for any open source solution which does not depend third party server.

Please suggest any open source solution to this which can convert html content to pdf effectively(Client Side will be preferable).

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, Mac or Linux, install [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). wkhtmltopdf is a command line utility to convert HTML to PDF using WebKit. You can download wkhtmltopdf from the linked webpage, or in many Linux distros it can be found in their repositories.

**Examples**

Convert a remote HTML file to PDF:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

Convert a local HTML file to PDF:

```
wkhtmltopdf example.html example.pdf
```

**[wkhtmltopdf usage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)** You can also display wkhtmltopdf help locally by running `wkhtmltopdf -H`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `htmltopdf` for convert HTML content into a pdf. I have used it and it fulfills my all requirements of converting HTML into pdf.
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2905-PHP-Convert-HTML-to-PDF-using-Web-services.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use TCPDF for converting HTML to PDF . its free and good features. I tried and its working perfectly even you can convert all html content like images ,or custom css into pdf without any problem by using TCPDF classes .

You can download form below link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/

Regards,
Sanjeev Kumar Goswami